# How do you store and mutate a bitmap/bitset using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, bit-manipulation, rdbms, bitset

I want to create a table column that stores a 500 byte bitmap (`500 bytes * 8 bits per byte = 4000 bits`) and do operations to mutate bits (set to 1 or 0) at certain indexes in the bitmap.

However, the [documentation page on bitmaps is mostly empty](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/bitmaps.html) leaving me with the [raw bit functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html) as the only guide. How do you create, count, read, and mutate a bitmap as a column type in MySQL?

Using `bin` and `lpad` you can print a 64 bit number out as a binary string.

```
LPAD(BIN(34), 64, '0')
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100010
```

However, how do you print out a binary/blob/varbinary string that might be 4000 bits long?

*(Note: not talking about bitmap indexes)*

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html

Comment: I think you need to use `varbinary` or `blob` datatype, there isn't an exposed bitmap datatype.

Comment: save the bitmap as blob and use php and https://imagemagick.org/index.php tp convert and edit nitmaps andfd then save it again

Comment: What's the point? You might as well just alter an Image and save it with `file_put_contents()`.

Comment: @nbk this question has nothing to do with images (or PHP).

Comment: I know, but a rdms is not a imaging software. it is possible with mysql 8 to manipulate bits, but not to change that many at once, so a specialized in a script dies the trick. Besides it is a comment and nit an answer.  you coud make a HExstring out of your bitmap and manipulate the hex values and then male a blob again, but as long as your bit manipulation is vague as now.

Comment: @nbk you're talking about the bitmap image format - I'm asking about bitmaps (also called bitsets) as a data structure. Two different things.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  If you need it for 5.7 or before, say so; I have some of the code you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use BLOB as data type and write a function wich will:

- extract the byte which needs to be updated
- change the bit in the byte
- insert the changed byte into the blob at the original position

Here is one implementation:

```
delimiter //
create function set_bit(b blob, pos int, val int) returns blob reads sql data
comment 'changes the bit at position <pos> (0: right most bit) to <val> in the blob <b>'
begin
    declare len int;      -- byte length of the blob
    declare byte_pos int; -- position of the affected byte (1: left most byte)
    declare bit_pos  int; -- position within the affected byte (0: right most bit)
    declare byte_val int; -- value of the affected byte

    set len = length(b);
    set byte_pos = len - (pos div 8);
    set bit_pos = pos mod 8;
    set byte_val = ord(substring(b, byte_pos, 1)); -- read the byte
    set byte_val = byte_val & (~(1 << bit_pos));   -- set the bit to 0
    set byte_val = byte_val | (val << bit_pos);    -- set the bit to <val>

    return insert(b, byte_pos, 1, char(byte_val)); -- replace the byte and return
end //
delimiter ;
```

A simple test:

```
create table test(id int, b blob);
insert into test(id, b) select 1, 0x000000;
insert into test(id, b) select 2, 0xffffff;
```

We have two blob bitmasks (3 bytes each) - One full of zeros and one full of ones. In both we set the bit at position `10` (11th bit from right) to `1` and the bit at position `11` (12th bit from right) to `0`.

```
update test set b = set_bit(b, 10, 1);
update test set b = set_bit(b, 11, 0);

select id, hex(b), to_base2(b) from test;
```

Result:

```
| id  | hex(b) | to_base2(b)                |
| --- | ------ | -------------------------- |
| 1   | 000400 | 00000000 00000100 00000000 |
| 2   | FFF7FF | 11111111 11110111 11111111 |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a1HwEQU7afCcnvPFvcxt69/0)

Note: `to_base2()` is a custom function that returns a string with a bit representation of a BLOB and is only used for presentation purpose.

This works for MySQL 5.x as well as for 8.0.

It is possible to implement it inline in a single expression (without the need of a function) - But that is rather unreadable:

```
update test t
cross join (select 10 as pos, 1 as val) i -- input
set t.b = insert(
  t.b,
  length(t.b) - (i.pos div 8),
  1,
  char(ord(
    substring(t.b, length(t.b) - (i.pos div 8), 1))
    & ~(1 << (i.pos mod 8))
    | (i.val << (i.pos mod 8)
  ))
);
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7FoBhK9a5Xz5s2WL1UfJVe/0)

In MySQL 8.0 it's a bit simpler, since we don't need to extract the byte and can use bit operations on blobs. But we need to make sure, that the oprerands are of the same length:

```
update test t
cross join (select 10 as pos, 1 as val) i -- input
set t.b = t.b
  & (~(concat(repeat(0x00,length(t.b)-1),char(1)) << i.pos))
  | (concat(repeat(0x00,length(t.b)-1),char(i.val)) << i.pos)
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tc5njDN7ynJQAaLuk7jH6z/0)

Another way:

```
update test t
cross join (select 10 as pos, 1 as val) i -- input
set t.b = 
  case when i.val = 1
    then t.b | concat(repeat(0x00,length(t.b)-1),char(1)) << i.pos
    else t.b & ~(concat(repeat(0x00,length(t.b)-1),char(1)) << i.pos)
  end
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oXKGkEd6tEFoHqPxQSnoL7/0)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I've been a bit busy lately and missed it. I'll start a second bounty to reward you.

Answer (score 5):

First, upgrade to MySQL 8.0. This won't work on earlier versions of MySQL.

You should use BINARY, VARBINARY, or BLOB, depending on the length of the bitfields you want to store.

```
mysql> create table mytable ( bits binary(500) );
ERROR 1074 (42000): Column length too big for column 'bits' (max = 255); use BLOB or TEXT instead

mysql> create table mytable ( bits blob(500) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

Use UNHEX() to form bitfields from hexadecimal strings. It's too difficult to work with binary bytes directly.

```
mysql> insert into mytable set bits = unhex(repeat('00', 500));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

You can use bitwise operators like `|`, `&`, `^`, and `~` with bitfields. But the strings must be the same length!

```
mysql> update mytable set bits = bits | b'01000';
ERROR 3513 (HY000): Binary operands of bitwise operators must be of equal length
```

It's inconvenient, but you must form strings that are the right length using CONCAT():

```
mysql> update mytable set bits = bits | unhex(concat(repeat('00', 498), 'ffff'));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Reading a bit string (I have shortened it for this display):

```
mysql> select hex(bits) from mytable\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
hex(bits): 000...000FFFF
```

The BIT_COUNT() function works:

```
mysql> select bit_count(bits) from mytable;
+-----------------+
| bit_count(bits) |
+-----------------+
|              16 |
+-----------------+

mysql> select bit_count(~bits) from mytable;
+------------------+
| bit_count(~bits) |
+------------------+
|             3984 |
+------------------+
```

By this time, you should sit back and think about whether SQL is the best tool for this task, even with the features of MySQL 8.0. You will find it more flexible and powerful to do bitwise work in most other programming languages.

Comment: I'm using a RDBMS for rest of the system so getting MySQL to work on bitmaps/bitsets/bitarrays would save me from having to pull down 500bytes just to set/unset a single bit. Apparently it's a lot harder for MariaDB/MySQL than I first thought. Not sure I'm ready to use a key/value store just for this one field though.

Comment: Well, I understand your reluctance to make your stack more complex, but that doesn't change the fact that MySQL doesn't have good functions for what you want to do.

Comment: @Xeoncross what's wrong with `update mytable set bits = bits | b'01000';` as suggested? You don't have to pull down 500bytes using this and I have tried it and it works pretty good on thousands of records with `SELECT` and `UPDATE`. I've even got it working with `BLOB` datatype and with SQLite.

Comment: The error message explains it. Both operands must be the same length, but in this case, `bits` is 500 bytes long, and the right hand operand is 1 byte long.